# Cannot cast to AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat in Nougat

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

This is my build.gradle

```
    defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

and a part of the layout

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/recents"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/anim_test"/>
```

and the class cast:

```
val np = convertView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.recents)
val anim = np.drawable as AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat
```

This works as expected on Lolipop (sdk 21) but fails on Nougat saying:

```
android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable cannot be cast to android.support.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat
```

What I dont get is, why does it return an AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat on sdk level 21 at all when AnimatedVectorDrawable is already supported by the system. And why does it return the AnimatedVectorDrawable in Nougat in spite of specifying `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`.

Comment: Same issue with support library 26.0.1. Solved by a workaround: a condition at runtime - you need to cast AnimatedVectorDrawable for lollipop and above, and AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat for prior lollipop.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Use `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.registerAnimationCallback` static method and it will do the job for you.

```
(drawable as Animatable).start()

AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.registerAnimationCallback(
        drawable,
        object : Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
            override fun onAnimationEnd(drawable: Drawable?) {
                postOnAnimation {
                    (drawable as Animatable).start()
                }
            }
        })
```

**Long answer:**

I was having the same problem when I was trying to loop an animated vector drawable. Until I found out the support library returns different classes (`AnimatedVectorDrawable` and `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat`) on different SDK levels.

It was not documented anywhere except this wonderful blog post of Nick Butcher:

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/re-animation-7869722af206

He says:

> Interestingly the support library currently uses the native version on API 24+ and the compat version prior despite the class being introduced in API 21. This enables it to supply bug fixes to APIs 21–23.

In the blog post the author also suggests other methods to work around this issue like using `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat#create` method and setting the drawable in the runtime.

I recommend you to read the whole article.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works as expected. In my case, I've incorrectly set the imageView with vector drawable instead of animated drawable. e.g: `iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_non_animated)` you should change this code to `iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_animated)`

Answer (score 14):

Instead of making checks with `API<21` you can cast to `Animatable` since both `AnimatedVectorDrawable` and `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat` implements it

```
var anim = mImageView.drawable as Animatable
    anim.start()
```

Answer (score 5):

I deal it like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView img;
    Button show, play, stop;
    AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat anim_show, anim_play, anim_stop;
    Object canim_show, canim_play, canim_stop;

    static {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        img = findViewById(R.id.img);

        show = findViewById(R.id.show);
        play = findViewById(R.id.play);
        stop = findViewById(R.id.stop);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21 ) {
            anim_show = (AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xunfei_show_animated_vector);
            anim_play = (AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xunfei_play_animated_vector);
            anim_stop = (AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xunfei_stop_animated_vector);

        }else{
            canim_show = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xunfei_show_animated_vector);
            canim_play = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xunfei_play_animated_vector);
            canim_stop = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xunfei_stop_animated_vector);
        }

        show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                    img.setImageDrawable(anim_show);
                    anim_show.start();
                } else {
                    img.setImageDrawable((AnimatedVectorDrawable) canim_show);
                    ((AnimatedVectorDrawable) canim_show).start();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a little late, but I just had the similar issue and I resolved it as follows. Maybe it will help someone.

When we are using **vectorDrawables** for animations, we need to do following three things:

1. Create an AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat from the vector drawable resource:

```kt
val drawable: AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat? =
          AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(context, R.drawable.animated_vector)
```

2. Cast this drawable to Animatable2Compat:

```kt
val animatable: Animatable2Compat = drawable as Animatable2Compat
```

3. Now register for callback provided by the support

```kt
animatable.registerAnimationCallback(object : Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
    override fun onAnimationEnd(drawable: Drawable?) {
      // Put code to execute after the animation is done
    }
  })
```

This is what I did. Please feel free to comment if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **SafaOrhan** for the working example.
I'll post the **Java** version with the imports.
I've used a class member variable to be able to stop the animation from another method.

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Animatable;
import android.support.graphics.drawable.Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback;
import android.support.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat;
import android.os.Handler;

public class MainActivity {
  private Animatable vectorAnimation;

  public void stopAnimation() {
    if (vectorAnimation != null) vectorAnimation.stop();
  }

  public void startAnimation() {
    Drawable vectorDrawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    vectorAnimation = (Animatable) vectorDrawable;
    AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.registerAnimationCallback(vectorDrawable, new AnimationCallback() {
      public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> vectorAnimation.start(), 1000);
      }
    });
    vectorAnimation.start();
  }
}
```